# Touring the United States

Tags: geography, graph-theory

You need to find a continuous path within the US that passes through all 48 contiguous states, visiting each one exactly once. If you start in Delaware, which state do you end in?

Comment: If there is no requirement that you stay within the US, there are many states you could end in.

Comment: @Bishop Pedant! :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The state you have to end in will be

> Maine, since it's the only state that only borders one other state, and therefore if you enter it from one state you can't leave it via another.

Here's a possible trip you can take:

> [image: Map]

Comment: Impressive - I wasn't expecting anyone to actually find a route! I never said you were allowed to cross water though... ;-)

Comment: Fair enough - the route could be altered to duck into Wisconsin from Minnesota and then down to Iowa, popping into Michigan between Indiana and Ohio. :)

Comment: Not sure why TroyAndAbed deleted his answer - he got a nice picture before you did, even though you got the answer first. I've voted to undelete.

Comment: I also have, though the Kentucky/Arkansas border is slightly dubious!

Comment: Nice! I love answers with pictures! We need more of them on this site.

Comment: @randal'thor My picture was wrong, I went through Missouri twice and Bailey already posted an answer so I deleted my post instead of editing it.

Comment: is there no bridge you can take between the north and south portions of whatever state that is south of Ontario? you wouldn't not even have to modify anything.

Comment: @Spacemonkey, I assume that there probably is, but I can't confirm it, and there's a way around it anyways. :) It's Michigan, by the way.

Comment: I'm tempted to google map that itinerary :P

Comment: Late reply to @Spacemonkey https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mackinac_Bridge